# ExpandableCell cell reuse issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, expandable, collapsable

I'm trying to use the library [ExpandableCell](https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell) to add collapsable table view cells to my app. I'm using the latest version of the library which is 1.3.0.

Below is the full code.

```
import UIKit
import ExpandableCell

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: ExpandableTableView!

    private var passengers = [Passenger]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.expandableDelegate = self

        passengers = [
            Passenger(id: 1, name: "Mark", trips: [Trip(id: 1, route: "NY to NJ")]),
            Passenger(id: 2, name: "Jesica", trips: [Trip(id: 1, route: "NY to NJ"), Trip(id: 2, route: "LA to LV")]),
            Passenger(id: 3, name: "Brian", trips: [Trip(id: 2, route: "Kansas City to Denver")])
        ]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: ExpandableDelegate {
    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return passengers.count
    }

    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PassengerCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PassengerCell
        let passenger = passengers[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = passenger.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(passenger.trips?.count ?? 0) trips"
        return cell
    }

    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, expandedCellsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewCell]? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TripCell
        let passenger = passengers[indexPath.row]
        if let trips = passenger.trips {
            var cells = [TripCell]()
            for trip in trips {
                cell.textLabel?.text = trip.route
                cells.append(cell)
            }
            return cells
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, heightsForExpandedRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [CGFloat]? {
        let count = passengers[indexPath.row].trips?.count ?? 0
        let heightArray = [CGFloat](repeating: 50, count: count)
        return heightArray
    }

    func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

The data is loaded correctly and the tableview appears as expected. But the problem is when you tap on a collapsed cell. It acts...weird.

[image]

Notice how some cells don't appear at all (the second group should show 2 yellow cells). And some cells appear in other groups that they don't belong in. It looks like a cell reuse issue.

I tried overriding the `prepareForReuse` method and reset the controls manually as well but that didn't work either.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    textLabel?.text = nil
    backgroundColor = nil
}
```

I saw some similar issues in the library's Github repo but there aren't any answers or fixes.

If anyone has used this library before, any idea what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyyklyu44y6c5ba/expand.zip?dl=0)

Comment: then  You can create your own!! Create tableview section and on tap on it add or remove rows

Comment: the problem is in you implementation of expandedCellsForRowAt, should be let passenger = passengers[indexPath.section]

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik No, because this tableview isn't a grouped tableview. The blue views are also cells, not section headerviews. I did try with `passengers[indexPath.section]` anyway just to see but then the data loading is wrong pus the same issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Demo Project...

In `expandedCellsForRowAt` in `ViewController`, you are creating **one** cell object, then assigning it different text values and appending it to an array.

```
func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, expandedCellsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewCell]? {

    // here, you create a cell object
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TripCell

    let passenger = passengers[indexPath.row]
    if let trips = passenger.trips {
        var cells = [TripCell]()
        for trip in trips {
            // here, you repeatedly set the text of the SAME cell object
            cell.textLabel?.text = trip.route
            cells.append(cell)
        }
        return cells
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use this instead:

```
func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: ExpandableTableView, expandedCellsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewCell]? {

    // Don't create the cell here
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TripCell

    let passenger = passengers[indexPath.row]
    if let trips = passenger.trips {
        var cells = [TripCell]()
        for trip in trips {
            // create a NEW cell for each trip (don't use indexPath)
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier) as! TripCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = trip.route
            cells.append(cell)
        }
        return cells
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you. I made the change and ran it. Unfortunately the cell disappearing issue still seems to be there.

Comment: Hmmm.... are you sure you made those exact changes? I can run your project and tap, tap, tap, tap away and the cells expand and collapse without problem.

Comment: Oh I just noticed the minor change. I was using this overload `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)` of the dequeue method. With the indexpath parameter. That seems to not work. I replaced it with `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TripCell.reuseIdentifier)` and the issue is gone! Thank you!